# Codeblocks debuggin on linux doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks

So, recently i bought a laptop that I'm gonna use to learn more about linux and i want to make my programs for uni there.  My problem is that everything works, except debugger, which doesn't stop at breakpooints at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeblocks doesn't stop at breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481928/codeblocks-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints)

Comment: The debugger is `gdb`. Did you read its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Using information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481928/codeblocks-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints), here's a list of things you may do to resolve this issue.

> - Clean and rebuild.
> - Ensure that (Build Options > Compiler Settings) "Produce debugging symbols" is checked, "Strip all symbols" is unchecked. Please ensure this is done in global settings **and** project settings. This fixed it for me.
> - Check so that there are no spaces/non-ASCII values in the project file path.
> - Check if you are running the debug version, not release. The executable from Release build will be `../bin/Release`, and the executable from a Debug build will be in `../bin/Debug`.
> - Check that Debugger in (Settings > Compiler > Toolchain Executables) is set to GDB/CDB Debugger:Default.
> - Update Code::Blocks (last resort).

Comment: i have tried this, the problem remains.
"warning gdb failed to set controlling terminal operation not permitted" this is the message i get.

Comment: @GPwoopzi Can you make a screenshot of the terminal window or where ever you got the message?