# CMakeListx.txt generated codeblocks project cannot stop in breakpoints

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

Ubuntu, I git clone https://github.com/NanoMichael/cLaTeXMath, and use below command to generate codeblocks project:

```
cmake .. -G"CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"
```

and the project created successfully, however, when I set breakpoints in the main function, and click Debug/Continue, the breakpoints cannot be stopped just like release version, the application can run very well, just cannot debug.

I checked some similar posts in stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481928/codeblocks-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints), and check the project, there are totally five build targets (I cannot find where these 5 defined); when I open "Build Options", click one target(LaTeX), just cannot find "Compiler Settings".

Then I check "Settings"->"Global compiler settings"->GNU GCC Compiler"->Compiler settings, and check "Produce debugging symbols [-g]", and rebuild, but still cannot stop on breakpoints.

I am not familar with codeblocks, please help, thanks!

Comment: You didn't tell cmake to create a debug build from what you're showing.

Comment: @sweenish, Thank you, you saved my life. I use cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. -G"CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles, it works now.